# Can not delete audio file

Tags: python

I have written code in Python in which a temp audio file is generated and played. For the next round of running the code the audio file needs to be deleted.

How can I delete that? While deleting through `os.remove` it is showing that file is open in another program, but I want to delete that audio file without closing the other program in which file might be there.

```
temp_file = f"temp.{speech.lang}.vlc"
with open(temp_file, "wb") as f:
    speech.save(temp_file)
try:
    pygame.mixer.music.load(temp_file)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
        pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
except pygame.error as e:
    print(f"[Playback Error]: {e}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"[Unexpected Playback Error]: {e}")

time.sleep(2.2)

if os.path.exists(temp_file):
    try:
        os.remove(temp_file)
        print(f"Successfully deleted temporary file: {temp_file}")
```

Comment: Your are probably missing `pygame.mixer.music.unload()` after the call to `stop()`

Comment: You don't use `f`, so try to delete line with `open(temp_file, "wb") as f:`

Comment: Not being able to delete a file which is held open by another process is an OS restriction which cannot safely be lifted. (My recommendation is always to get rid of Windows.)

Answer (score 1):

I take a lucky guess for that you are working under Windows, where opened files cannot be deleted, unlike for Unix-ish operating systems using the inode concept for decoupeling. (See this [unix.stackexchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49306) for details.)

Conclusion: You need to manage to have the file not opened when calling `os.remove()`. Note that `pygame.mixer.music.load()` is provided in two variantes, one taking a filename while the other taking a file object and an optional namehint, see [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.load).

You can use the python module `io` to have a in-memory file object and pass the file content into it:

```
import io

try:    
    with open(temp_file, "rb") as f:
        buf = io.BytesIO(f.read())
    
    buf.seek(0)
    pygame.mixer.music.load(buf, "vlc")

    ...

    if os.path.exists(temp_file):
        os.remove(temp_file)
        print(f"Successfully deleted temporary file: {temp_file}")
```

See also this related [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53922845/8756717) on the necessity to rewind the `buf` object with `seek()`.

In fact, depending on what you precisely want to achieve, you may get rid of the `temp_file` business altogether and let `speech.save()` save to `buf` directly. This would remove the detour over disk IO.